# Find and Replace with correct URL

Tags: regex, erlang, redirect

There are region specific URLs for various websites like `google.co.in` or `google.co.uk` for `google.com`, So for the major sites like google, facebook, linkedin, I want to replace their region specific URLs with all region URL.

For example for google, it should be redirected to https://www.google.com/webhp?pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr.

The solution which I was trying:

1) Take the part of URL `google.co.in`(using regex) and replace it with `google.com` (using `re:replace`)

2) For storing of initial and replacement URL, I'm thinking to use `orddict`, where `{key,value}={"...//google.co.region/...","...//google.com/..."}`, region can be `in` or `uk` or any other, so how to take that region into consideration if I'm using orddict as keystore ?

But I'm not sure how to actually implement this in erlang or whether my proposed solution will work properly ?

I'm doing this for my messenger app, so whenever user enters URL, it doesn't show preview of URL where my server is located, instead atleast show it in english.(as per now ,for facebook, my app shows preview in russian)

Answer (score 0):

There's built-in regex module in Erlang: `http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html`

As for your solution, it really feels like a crutch for functionality better achieved with smart networking. Or you can try making requests for a preview on client's side, not server, for example.

Comment: I can't make requests on client side, because in case of slow network, it will take a lot of time to show preview.

Comment: Well, it will take alot of time to send preview from server in case of client's slow network too. If you still want to use server-side preview loading and you want different locales for one website for some reason, you should consider having proxies all around the world or stick with strict regex replace with global site